# Banco de Dados Não Relacionais vs Banco de Dados Relacionais

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Há algum tempo atrás eu fiquei em dúvida sobre as diferenças entre esses dois modelos, eu cheguei a procurar na internet mas não achei nada que me tirasse a dúvida por isso, vou fazer algumas perguntas.

> 1 - O que é Modelo relacional e não relacional e suas diferenças?

Gostaria saber as características  de cada um e as diferenças entre eles.

> 2- Vantagens e desvantagens de cada um.

Gostaria de saber as vantagens e desvantagens e uma breve explicação sobre elas.

> 3- Exemplo de aplicações que usam os diferentes modelos e porque.

Eu gostaria de saber em quais casos cada um deles são usados e porque, se possível com exemplos reais.

Aceito indicações de matérias para estudo, Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A diferença essencial entre as duas teconologia é que uma é baseada em esquema (Relacional) e a outra não (Não relacional).

Para trabalhar com um banco SQL (Relacional) a primeira coisa que voce precisa fazer é projetar a estrutura do banco, isto é, voce não consegue inserir um dado se não tiver previamente definido os "esquemas" das tabelas, enquanto que na tecnologia NoSQL (Não relacional). isto não é necessário.

Vamos a um exemplo: 
Vamos supor que voce quisesse guardar nomes e telefones de clientes em um banco de dados.

Em um banco relacional, a primeira coisa que precisariamos fazer seria definir o esquema das tabelas no banco (definir sua estrutura), como sabemos que um cliente pode ter mais de um telefone e que cada um pode ter quantidades diferentes de números de telefones, o ideal seria definirmos 2 tabelas: Uma pra o registro do codigo e o nome do cliente e outra para os registros de seus telefones:

Tabela Cliente (Tabcli):

```
id, Integer
Nome, Character, 50
```

Tabela Telefones (Tabtel):

```
id_cliente, integer
Fone, Character, 15
```

Dessa forma cada cliente terá apenas um registro na tabela tabcli e, no mínimo um, ou quantos forem os números que ele possui na tabela Tabtel. A ligação (ou a relação, do termo "relacional") entre uma tabela e outra seria feita através dos campos Tabcli.id -> Tabetel.id_cliente, dessa forma para apresentar as informações de um cliente seria preciso seleciona-lo na tabela Tabcli, e filtrar todos os registros na Tabtel cujo id_cliente coresspondesse ao id na Tabcli.

Agora vejamos como o mesmo exemplo seria registrado em um banco no-sql como por exemplo o mongodb, em primeiro lugar voce não precisaria definir um esquema prévio para guardar as informaçẽos, voce precisaria somente fazer diretamente o registro em um formato que o banco "entenda", no caso do [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/), json. No mongo, o correspondente a tabelas é chamado de collections, então bastaria:

```
db.clientes.save( {_id: 1, fones: ["123-4567", "456-7899"]})
```

Para acessar, basta localizar o _id do cliente e voce já terá acesso a todas as informações daquele cliente, sem a necessidade de acessar outra entidade do banco e/ou criação de filtros, etc.

A explanação acima é bem resumida, há inúmeros outros detalhes tanto no lado relacional quanto no não relacional, no primeiro por exemplo há vários elementos para garantir a integridade e a não redundancia dos dados, que não foram mencionados.

Uma outra caracterisca central dos bancos relacionais é uso exclusivo (Veja o tópico "**É o fim do SQL?**) da linguagem SQL para acesso aos dados enquanto que nos não relacionais isso não se aplica, porém é preciso atentar para o fato de que um banco não relacional não abomina o SQL, aliás o termo NoSQL pode induzir ao erro de supor que seja Não SQL, quando na verdade é "Not **Only** Structured Query Language"

**Vantagens dos bancos não relacionais:**
A vantagem número um dos bancos não relacionais é a escalabilidade, claro que o esquema rigido dos bancos relacionais torna dificil, por exemplo, aumentar um nó em um cluster de banco de dados, outra vantagem é a flexibilidade da estruturação que além de tornar a escalabilidade mais fácil facilita a inserção e acesso aos dados. Outra caracterisca que talvez possa ser vista como vantagem é a manipulação de dados por APIs orientadas a objetos enquanto no modelo relacional somente via SQL. Pode-se citar ainda, como desvantagem, a relativa imaturidade do Nosql.

**Vantagens dos bancos Relacionais:**
Enquanto que no modelo não relacional, a consistencia pode ser considerada fraca, no modelo relacional há uma forte consistencia de dados, um dos preços para isso é a estrutura menos flexivel. Outra vantagem é a confiabilididade, modelos relacionais suportam a propriedade [ACID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) (Atomicidade, Consistência, Isolamento e Durabilidade), Outra vantagem do SQL é a padronização e normalização. Finalmente pode-se citar como vantagem a maturidade do SQL.

**Quem usa NoSQL e por quê:** 
O motivo principal e crucial para a escolha do NoSQL é a escala, então o que os grandes "players" do mercado fazem é eleger areas onde a confiablidade e consistencia podem ser, até certo ponto, ignoradas em favor da escalabilidade para utilizar essa tecnologia. É importante frizar, que os bancos NoSQL mais conhecidos no mercado, foram criados por esses players.

Exatamente pelo motivo dos bancos do modelo NoSQL evitarem a propriedade ACID, os grandes players como Google e Facebook evitam utiliza-los em aplicações que exigem grande consistencia e confiabilididade. Abaixo reproduzo ([desse link](http://blog.outsourcing-partners.com/2012/10/why-nosql-database-is-used-by-facebook-google-and-linkedin-applications/)) uma lista de aplicações em que os modelos não relacionais foram utilizados.

```
| Candidate | Usage                                 | Tools                 |
|-----------|---------------------------------------|-----------------------|
| Facebook  | Email search system                   | Cassandra (Apache)    |
| Google    | Used for generatin and modifying data | Big Table (By Google) |
| LinkedIn  | Millions of reads an writes per day   | Voldemor (By LinedIn) |
```

**É o fim do SQL?** 
A palavra "disruptiva" é um dos vocábulos mais propagados na área de tecnologia e, segundo a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnologia_disruptiva),  é um termo descrevendo a inovação tecnológica, produto, ou serviço, que utiliza uma estratégia "disruptiva", em vez de "revolucionário" ou "evolucionário", para derrubar uma tecnologia existente dominante no mercado. Em várias páginas do site do banco não relacional [mongdb](https://www.mongodb.com/) é possível encontrar referências a esse termo fazendo alusão à (**im**)provavel decadencia do modelo relacional.

Estaria o modelo relacional em perigo se o NoSQL conseguisse atingir o mesmo nível de consistencia e confiabilidade? Isso seria possível sem perder suas principais vantagens? E se o modelo SQL conseguisse implementar algumas das vantagens do NoSQL?

Felizmente a resposta para a última pergunta é que isso ja está acontecendo, foi com uma grata surpresa que descobri recentemente que [já é possível definir campos JSON em pelo menos um banco relacional, o Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html).

**Not Only SQL** 
Participei de um trabalho feito para um curso em 2012, em que apresentamos um breve resumo sobre NoSQL. [Essa apresentação](https://prezi.com/n_dchgptz3do/nosql/?webgl=0) pode  apontar caminhos para uma pesquisa mais profunda. Veja-a em tela cheia.

Comment: Excelente explicação, parabéns!