# Nodejs com Banco de dados Relacional

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, mongodb

Galera, cheguei em uma estrada de dois caminhos e não sei qual seguir.
O problema é o seguinte: Estou iniciado o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação que é basicamente parecido com uma rede social, vai ter chat, timeline... essas coisas que tem no facebook, mas é voltada a outro negócio. Gostaria muito de usar NodeJS + MongoDB para o desenvolvimento da API, porém, algumas amigos desenvolvedores já relataram problemas quanto a necessidade de relacionamento entre documents, a partir disso fui buscar a alternativa do banco relacional, pensei no PostgreSQL, nisso vem outra dúvida, NodeJS vale a pena com banco de dados relacional?

Comment: Para se usar Postgres com Sequelize é quase identico com MySQL. *problemas quanto a necessidade de relacionamento entre documents* - vai depender muito da arquitetura, NoSQL tem suas vantagens principalmente quando se exige escalabilidade. O facebook também usa [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) que é um NoSQL.

Comment: Postgres, a partir da versão 9 (salvo engano) tem campos JSON, claro que não é uma implementação completa "like mongo", mas da para fazer muita coisa do mundo `nosql`, veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195072/7412). No finalzinho tem um link para essas features do Postgres.